Angular 18.2 Native Federation, Firebase "serve" command doesn't work as expected
I am trying to create an angular project to work with the Firebase (@angular/fire) and Native Federation in an NX Monorepo.
This is my setup:
tsconfig.base.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@ethi/common": ["libs/common/src/index.ts"],
      "@ethi/schema": ["libs/schema/src/index.ts"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "@ethi/source",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {},
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^18",
    "@angular/forms": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~18.2.0",
    "es-module-shims": "^1.5.12",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-architects/native-federation": "^18.2.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^18.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^18.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^18.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~18.2.0",
    "@nx/angular": "19.7.3",
    "@nx/eslint": "19.7.3",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "19.7.3",
    "@nx/jest": "19.7.3",
    "@nx/js": "19.7.3",
    "@nx/node": "19.7.3",
    "@nx/web": "19.7.3",
    "@nx/workspace": "19.7.3",
    "@schematics/angular": "~18.2.0",
    "@swc-node/register": "~1.9.1",
    "@swc/core": "~1.5.7",
    "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.11",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "18.16.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/utils": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint": "~8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-node": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "~14.1.0",
    "nx": "19.7.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~5.5.2"
  }
}

app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(appRoutes), 
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environments.firebase), 
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()), 
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()), 
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
  ],
};

app.routes.ts
const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['login']);
const redirectLoggedInToHome = () => redirectLoggedInTo(['home']);

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin },
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin },
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginPageComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { authGuardPipe: redirectLoggedInToHome },
    },
];

app.component.ts
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'broker-bi';
}

When I run the application through nx run broker-bi:serve-original it runs as expected but with no native federation. When I run it through nx run broker-bi:serve I get the following error:
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
    at getApp (_angular_fire_auth.r5LpLF_iJr-dev.js:1538:25)
    at getAuth (_angular_fire_auth.r5LpLF_iJr-dev.js:9174:24)
    at _angular_fire.hX3GNn6leI-dev.js:1316:44
    at _angular_fire.hX3GNn6leI-dev.js:1263:57
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:369:28)
    at _ZoneImpl.run (zone.js:111:43)
    at _NgZone.runOutsideAngular (_angular_core.lGU3keLAQ5-dev.js:4134:24)
    at runOutsideAngular (_angular_fire.hX3GNn6leI-dev.js:1263:33)
    at _angular_fire.hX3GNn6leI-dev.js:1316:17
    at app.config.ts:24:23

What am I dong wrong?
